# How do you set an RSS mimetype using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, rss

I have a Python script that I run that generates the text for an RSS feed, which I then serve with the following line in Flask:

```
return render_template('rss.xml', mimetype='application/rss+xml')
```

However, the [RSS validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.residentmar.io%2Ffeed) says that my content is still being served with the `text/html` mimetype. How come?

Here is the complete method:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path == '':
        return render_template('about.html', most_recent=request.url_root + post_list[len(post_list) - 1]['route'])
    elif path == 'feed':
        return render_template('rss.xml', mimetype='application/rss+xml')
    elif path in post_paths:
        index = post_paths.index(path)
        post = post_list[index]
        return render_template('posts/' + post['template'],
                               id=index + 1,
                               date="{0:02d}/{1:02d}/{2}".format(post['date'].month, post['date'].day,
                                                                 post['date'].year),
                               title=post['title'],
                               most_recent=request.url_root + post_list[len(post_list) - 1]['route']
                               )
    elif path in raws_list:
        return render_template('visualizations/' + path)
    else:
        abort(404)
```

Comment: You should probably break that view up into multiple ones. It will remove a lot of you if statements.

Comment: I kind of agree, I should. What's the accepted way of structuring an application like this one? A bunch of `serve_this_content_type()` submethods?

Comment: Based on what you've shared, you should have an `about` endpoiint at `'/'`, a `feed` endpoint at `/feed'`, a `post` endpoint at something like `'/posts/<int:month>/<int:day>/<int:year>/<int:id>'`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the header on a response object. You can pass the result of `render_template` to Flask's `make_response` and set it there.

```
from flask import make_response

# snip

rss_xml = render_template('rss.xml')
response = make_response(rss_xml)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/rss+xml'
return response
```